# Flutter Crash in IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, crash

when I run my flutter project in a simulator or real phone my app run and after less than a minute my app crash.

I think the problem is shown when I add the AdMob banner in the project but not sure.

```
2021-04-11 23:05:29.307292+0430 Runner[5907:30444] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20421af6 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177e78 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2049e77f _CFThrowFormattedException + 194
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff204a9ec4 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:].cold.5 + 0
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2048ccb7 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 235
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20420773 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 49
    6   Runner                              0x000000010b66ac17 -[FLTAdInstanceManager onAdLoaded:] + 183
    7   Runner                              0x000000010b667757 -[FLTBannerAd adViewDidReceiveAd:] + 87
    8   Runner                              0x000000010b556133 GAD_GADBannerView_x86_64_7_69_0 + 6481
    9   Runner                              0x000000010b5ae61a __copy_helper_block_e8_32s40s48s56s64b72w + 188
    10  Runner                              0x000000010b5ae6c6 __copy_helper_block_e8_32s40s48s56s64b72w + 360
    11  Runner                              0x000000010b5ae2cc __destroy_helper_block_e8_32s40s48w + 908
    12  Runner                              0x000000010b5adea6 GAD_GADInternalBannerView_x86_64_7_69_0 + 6198
    13  Runner                              0x000000010b5ae536 __destroy_helper_block_e8_32s40s48w + 1526
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001128c57ec _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001128c69c8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001128d4e75 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1152
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038fdbb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038a63e __CFRunLoopRun + 2685
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203896d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff2c257db3 GSEventRunModal + 139
    21  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24696cf7 -[UIApplication _run] + 912
    22  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2469bba8 UIApplicationMain + 101
    23  Runner                              0x000000010b45761b main + 75
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff2025a3e9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPhone 12 (E2DE847C-4F2E-4E1B-8DC4-86F7533CEDE9) - Runtime: iOS 14.4 (18D46) - DeviceType: iPhone 12
```

I don't know where it is from but after that the app terminate,

this is my flutter version,

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.3, on macOS 11.0.1 20B29 darwin-x64, locale
    en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.55.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

and the packages that I'm use,

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.2
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.3
  image_picker: ^0.7.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.4
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.0
  cached_network_image: ^2.5.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  firebase_messaging: ^9.0.1
  photo_view: ^0.11.1
  uuid: ^3.0.1
  image: ^3.0.1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.0.0
  async: ^2.4.2
  http: ^0.13.0
  location: ^4.1.1
  geocoder: ^0.2.1
  flare_flutter: ^2.0.6
  package_info: ^2.0.0
  provider: ^5.0.0
  random_string: ^2.1.0
  rxdart: ^0.25.0
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.8.0
  flutter_secure_storage: ^4.1.0
  latlong: ^0.6.1
  shimmer: ^1.1.2
  persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^3.1.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0
  google_mobile_ads: ^0.11.0+4
```

Comment: This is the cause of your error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'`

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad So any idea how to solve this issue?